# Get Sub Folders and Filenames From Main Folder in Gridview Control in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, directory, subdirectory

I need shows the **subdirectory** and **file names** from a **subdirectory** into a **GridView** control.

On the server I have this folder structure :

```
MainFolder 
 1_Subfolder 
 2_Subfolder 
 3_Subfolder
```

For each **SubFolder** I have variable number of files.

I need first show the **MainFolder** and click on **MainFolder** show the **Subfolder** and click on the **Subfolder** show all files.

If click on the file name I need the download of this file.

I thinked use the **Directory class** but without success, because this code show all **Subfolder** and all files for each **Subfolder**:

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
gvDownload.DataSource = allfiles;
gvDownload.DataBind();
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/591024/UsingplusaplusGridviewplustoplusdisplayplusFileplu) and try.